# Arduino accelerometer MPU-6050

Tags: arduino, accelerometer, sensors

This might sound like a very silly question, so I apologize if this is something very simple but I just cannot get my head around it. I am trying to understand what the data provides in terms of real time information, for example, the MPU-6050:

Gyroscope - is a 16 bit data register with a range from (0 <-> 65535)
There is a selection of ranges  (±250, ±500, ±1000, and ±2000°/sec)

If the range is set to ±250°/sec, is the reading 360/65535 = 0.0054 resolution?

What does °/sec mean, if the sensor does not move and reads zero and then turned quickly does it mean it will be reading the angle at the set range? For example, if the range was set to ±2000°/sec and it was moved 200° would the read move from 0 to (2/65535 *200) and keep sending this value once the sensor stopped moving?

Accelerometer - is a 16 bit data register with a range from (0 <-> 65535)
There is a selection of ranges (±2g, ±4g, ±8g and ±16g)

If the sensor is not moving, completely flat the reading will be 0?
If the sensor is shocked at 2g will the max reading be 65535 (if set of 2g, with a resolution of 2/65535)
If the sensor is shocked at 16g will the max reading be 65535 (if set of 16g, with a resolution of 16/65535))

Comment: Regarding gyroscope, º/sec means it is measuring rotation speed. To obtain the rotation you should integrate the speed over time.
Regarding accelerometer, if you put it on a flat surface, it will read 1g in the direction of gravity, as it is an acceleration.

Comment: Thank you for the response, does that mean if I rotate the device 125° in one second  I will get  65535/2 response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main documents regarding the MPU6050, and those are the [datasheet](https://www.invensense.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Datasheet1.pdf) and the [register map](https://www.invensense.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Register-Map1.pdf).

The gyro measurements are stored in the GYRO_XOUT, GYRO_YOUT, GYRO_ZOUT parameters, as you can see in the register map document, page 31. Each parameter is stored as a 2-complement signed 16 bit value split into two 8-bit registers: the GYRO_xOUT_L and _H.

In the same page, you can see the sensitivity for each full-scale range. For example, if your FSR is +/- 250º/sec, and you want to measure 1º/sec, the GYRO_xOUT parameter should read 131 counts.

The accelerometer-related registers can be seen in the same document, page 29. The idea is the same, two 8-bit registers to form a 2-complement signed 16-bit value, and the sensitivity values for each FSR.

Regarding your question in comments, if you rotate the device 125º in a second, at constant rotation speed, you should read 16375 in the rotation registers during the movement. This value comes from 131 counts/(º/sec) * 125º/sec = 16375 counts.